# Import data from sensor into node-red

Tags: sensor, mqtt, nodered

I’m doing a uni assignment on Iot, and we are doing a soil moisture system with a water pump. One stipulation is that we need to use Node-Red.

List of components

*MCP3008 8-channel ADC
Raspberry Pi 4

*Dfrobot Gravity: Analog Waterproof Capacitive Soil Moisture Sensor

*Piico Dev oLED

*Piico Dev adapter for raspberry pi

*Dfrobot: Amphibious Horizontal Submersible Pump

*Using Mac and controlling raspberry pi through the terminal.

Okay. Im a full rookie here… Apart from connecting a dht22 humidity this is my first project…. Here’s where I’m at:

Installed MCP3XXX library and done this…. sudo pip3 install adafruit-circuitpython-mcp3xxx.`As per everything on this thread https://learn.adafruit.com/mcp3008-spi-adc/python-circuitpython`

Set up a mosquito mqtt broker and
node red is connected (check screen shots)`
[image]

Heres the code that has been stored
in ` “/home/pi/./code.py”

```
# SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

import busio
import digitalio
import board
import adafruit_mcp3xxx.mcp3008 as MCP
from adafruit_mcp3xxx.analog_in import AnalogIn

# create the spi bus
spi = busio.SPI(clock=board.SCK, MISO=board.MISO, MOSI=board.MOSI)

# create the cs (chip select)
cs = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D5)

# create the mcp object
mcp = MCP.MCP3008(spi, cs)

# create an analog input channel on pin 0
chan = AnalogIn(mcp, MCP.P0)

print("Raw ADC Value: ", chan.value)
print("ADC Voltage: " + str(chan.voltage) + "V")
```

Now I run this
code: ` python3 ./code.py and I get data coming in from the sensor. And it does change when I put the sensor in water… so that seems to be working (Look at screenshot).

[image]

So what I need is to import this into node-red I’m assuming we need to use an “mqtt in” node, but I just can’t figure it out… I’ve watched probably 40 different YouTube videos, and it looks so easy but nothing seems to work.

When I use a “mqtt in”node I get nothing coming through
the debugger… It shows it is connect but no error msg or data. (check
screenshots) `

[image]
[image]
[image]

Is there a
different way to import the data coming in from the raspberry pi, or is there
something I’m missing?`

I think I will need to calibrate the sensor and somehow set the parameters to interpret the data as come sort of high, medium, low soil moisture level. Not sure if i can do this in Node-Red or do I have to do this in Terminal.

And I haven’t even
attempted to connect the water pump and oLED ,to display if the soil is wet or
not, yet. So many more questions will
probably be on the way haha`

Can some legend out
there same me!!`

Comment: You need to break your project into component tasks and debug each independently. No experienced developer writes a complex task and expecting to debug as a whole.

Comment: Way too much in 1 go. Regardless, I do not think I saw a mention of a MQTT broker anywhere in your question (other than when you were quoting  Adafruit instruction).  Forget NodeRed for now. You need to publish your data to a broker (run mosquito on your RPi). I would do this and subscribe to that data on the command line to see if it works. Then try to do the same (subscribe) w/NodeRED. BTW, MQTT is supposed to go over the network. Even if you try to do it all in 1 device.  If you have network problems and are not familiar with solving them ... well, that could be a problem all in its self.

Comment: Hey yeah sorry was alot.. I thought if i provided everything know then someone can get a full grasp of where i'm at... thanks for your input.. i set up mosquitto broker, but how do I publish the data, and then how do i subscribe to that? its all so confusing

Comment: MQTT is how NodeRED connects to most of the outside world.  If you don't understand MQTT, then a NodeRED session isn't going to be very productive. Also, most if not all the stackexchange web sites are designed for 1 clear concise question at a time. Break down your project into simple tasks and ask questions should things not go as you expected. If that takes multiple questions/answers, great! Also, keep in mind the purposes of MQTT. To relay information around a network. Even if the subscriber & publisher are not on line at the same time. This was the prob IBM solved on a pipeline project.

Comment: BTW, as an extra incentive, once you get MQTT working, I believe io.adafruit.com has a free service which publishes a limited amount of data (that's why it's free) by sending io.adafruit.com (secure) MQTT messages.